# Axios Interceptor for Auth Token refresh returns error in which error.response is undefined

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement axios interceptor which intercepts the response to check if it is a 401 error , in that case new refresh token need to be generated and retry the original request .

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
return response
},
function (error) {
const originalRequest = error.config;
if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {

   originalRequest._retry = true;
   return axios.post('/auth/token',
       {
          {body}
       })
       .then(res => {
           if (res.status === 201) {
               // 1) put token to LocalStorage
               localStorageService.setToken(res.data);

               // 2) Change Authorization header
               axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorageService.getAccessToken();

               // 3) return originalRequest object with Axios.
               return axios(originalRequest);
           }
       })
 }

   // return Error object with Promise
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I am trying to fetch refresh token from aws cognito and all the apis are deployed in lamba aws . I am getting error as I am expecting error.response object which is undefined now . Some suggested to be CORS preflight issue, but it would be great if someone have a solution for this .

Comment: `error.response` can be undefined for some kind of errors so you should always test that first. Change condition to `if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry)` and see what happens. If it is a CORS issue, there should be some message in browser console about response being blocked....

Comment: Yes there is CORS error in console, Prefilght response error . How can i solve the network error issue , as I need to manipulate the code for auth refresh token generation and attach the same as Authorization header in retry of original request .